# Code insertion point of VS auto generated event handler methods

Tags: c#

How to set insertion point for Visual Studio C# auto generated event handlers?

For example double clicking button in UI form designer generates:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
}
```

I like to set the location where this code is auto generated.  I have lots of methods in my application and like to control where new prototype event methods are inserted. It's not entered at current cursor location and so far I can't find how to force the insertion point to location I like.

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me...